# Ubermenu DROP UP Submenus instead of drop down - WordPress Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to have menus that drop up instead of drop down in Ubermenu (WordPress Plugin)?

I have a navigation bar at the bottom of the screen when loaded, but I need the drop downs to go upwards on hover.

Answer (score 0):

usually a dropdown has absolute position, and some setting like `top: 20px` (or whatever to move it below its parent element). So you could replace that with a `bottom: 20px` setting (with an appropriate value), but you'd probably also have to overwrite the initial `top` setting of the plugin, using something like `top: initial`, `top: auto` or `top: none`, and also better add `!important` to that.